# sql Difference between >=All and MAX

Tags: sql, oracle

Whats the difference between

Statement 1:

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world x
  WHERE x.area >= ALL
    (SELECT y.area FROM world y
    WHERE y.continent=x.continent)
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT continent,name,area FROM world x
WHERE x.area =(SELECT MAX(y.area) FROM world y
WHERE y.continent=x.continent)
```

It seems to give me different results AS shown below.

For statement 1:
http://s8.postimg.org/6t8588cz9/ss1.jpg

For statement 2:
http://s4.postimg.org/5lfo10xul/ss2.jpg

Isn't >= ALL logically equivalent to SELECT MAX()?

The second statement which uses the MAX returns a superset of the first statement.(More results as compared to the first statement) I cant figure out why it is so.

Comment: Is that a copy/paste error? What do you mean "different results"?

Comment: The second statement which uses the MAX returns a superset of the first statement.(More results as compared to the first statement)
I cant figure out why it is so.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The second statement ought to return a *subset* of the first because you are only including rows equal to the greatest area (as opposed to greater than or equal). Can you reproduce this behavior in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Question 6 in this link
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

If you try  the two statement ,you would see the results that i meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this particular data set is that some of the continents like  'Africa' and 'Europe' have null data for area (E.g. Netherlands in Europe)

Add area>0 to your first query and you should see the same results

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world x
  WHERE x.area >= ALL
    (SELECT y.area FROM world y
    WHERE y.continent=x.continent and area>0)
```

Comment: Sorry thats what I meant. Corrected, Thanks!

Comment: I think that is population :)

Comment: Oops! Completely missed that, due to the SQL being filled in by default to select on population. :) You're right.

Comment: Thanks. The discrepancy is due to the null values.

Answer (score 2):

An important difference is that

```
x = (select max(y) ...)
```

will only be true when `x` is *exactly* equal to the maximum `y`, so `x` must be found in `y`, but

```
x >= all (select y ...)
```

will be true for *any* values of `x` greater than (or equal to) all values of `y`, so `x` may be *not found* in `y`.

Comment: The question has the same column for `x` and for `y` though, so that shouldn't make a difference.